# Unable to parse this kind of string to java

Tags: java, json, gson

i have this string of values and don't understand how to get the object array name and values of object items in java.

```
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"Rajesh" , "lastName":"Putta" }, 
{ "firstName":"Rajesh" , "lastName":"P" }, 
{ "firstName":"first name" , "lastName":"last name" }
]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7663467/302916

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You need to show us that you've at least Googled some solution.

Comment: in my Netbeans IDE i used json-simple.jar file and then i tried examples with jackson and Gson libraries. But i did not remove those libraries and kept them on classpath. But the examples i tried with were org.json and not with the org.simple. so the examples i copied into my editor showed lot of errors. I got it fixed. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a json stirng.  Check more about it [here](http://www.json.org/):

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange
>   format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for
>   machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the
>   JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition -
>   December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language
>   independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of
>   the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript,
>   Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal
>   data-interchange language.

You can parse it using a json parser such as

[**simpleJson**](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

[**Jackson**](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

[**GSon**](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Try these parsers, if you get stuck with the code then share your code and the problem.

Comment: yes i tried a lot of examples. but i didn't get what i wanted and i'm new to this field. when i tried to do this some had used maps and lists. But i want to know a simple way since my json knowledge is not much better.

Comment: @kolithagunathilaka Never mind sharing your code on SO. You will see more responses when you share your code.

Comment: @kolithagunathilaka You can accept the answer if it was helpful for you. Accepting an answer benefit others facing the same problem.

Comment: yes sorry for the late.